Workbook_BeforeClose event with multiple criteria to validate entries
I want to create a Workbook_BeforeClose event with these criteria.
If (L5:L63) has ANY cells that are not empty, then (L65) AND (L66) must have data entered prior to the workbook closing.
If (L5:L63) has ANY cells that are not empty, and EITHER (L65) or (L66) are empty, then call a message box to address which cell needs to have data input.
If (L5:L63) has ANY cells that are not empty and BOTH (L65:L66) are empty, call a message box that tells the user to fill out both (L65 and L66).
If all of the above criteria are met, I want to exit the sub with no messages and be able to close the workbook.
I have formulas on another worksheet in the workbook to better check that all of my conditions are met.

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Instruction & Data Input" Then

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For Each rngCell In Range("L5:L" & lngLstRow)
        If rngCell.Value = "" Then
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
                           
    For Each rngCell In Range("L5:L" & lngLstRow)

        If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Offset(2, 0) = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Please add battery terminal  connection (+) resistance reading to sheet in yellow highlighted cells. This reading is taken from the incoming charger controller connection to the first battery terminal lug. ")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
            
    For Each rngCell In Range("L5:L" & lngLstRow)
            
        If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Offset(3, 0) = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Please add battery terminal  connection (-) resistance reading to sheet in yellow highlighted cells. This reading is taken from the last battery to the out going charger controller connection.")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End If
End Sub


I believe that the first check is what is causing the issue. I have also tried the code without the first check (if range is empty then exit sub) and it fired the message box for each instance. Right now, as it is written above, it allows the workbook to close and doesn't display the message boxes.

Your requirements are contradictory:  "the two cells [L65:L66] need to have values in them (or one cell depending on if one or the other are empty)" and do not close workbook unless "b) data is input into cells L65 AND L66`

Also you can select any other sheet and close the workbook, regardless of what's in Col L on Instruction & Data Input

Thank you for the response Tim. So is the 1st issue that the range is L5:L ? Since L65 and L66 are in the "L" column it is preventing the code to execute? For the 2nd one; should I remove active sheet portion? Or should I change this to a worksheet event and move it to the worksheet this is checking?

Try this out:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, lngLstRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, v, stopClose As Boolean, colOffset
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction & Data Input") 'reference specific worksheet
    
    lngLstRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row 'last cell in Col L with content
    If lngLstRow < 5 Then Exit Sub  'range is empty?

    'check each cell in Col L used range
    For Each c In ws.Range("L5:L" & lngLstRow).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            For Each colOffset In Array(2, 3) 'checking cells 2 and 3 columns to the right
                With c.Offset(0, colOffset)  'the cell to be checked
                    .FormatConditions.Delete 'clear any existing CF flag
                    If Len(.Value) = 0 Then  'empty?
                        AddCFFill .Cells(1), vbRed 'flag the cell
                        stopClose = True           'at least one cell with a problem
                    End If 'required cell is empty
                End With
            Next colOffset  'check next column
        End If
    Next c
    
    If stopClose Then  'any cells with a problem? Alert the user and cancel close
        MsgBox "Some required values are missing! (see red-filled cells)" & vbLf & _
               "...rest of message here describes what's missing"
        
        Cancel = True 'cancel the close
    End If
    
End Sub

'Add a fill to a cell/range using a FormatCondition
'  Allows to revert to any previous fill on deleting the CF
Sub AddCFFill(c As Range, clr As Long)
    With c.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=TRUE")
        .SetFirstPriority
        .Interior.Color = clr
    End With
End Sub

Edit - updated:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, v, stopClose As Boolean, msg As String
    Dim L65empty As Boolean, L66empty As Boolean
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instruction & Data Input") 'reference specific worksheet
    
    If Application.CountA(ws.Range("L5:L63")) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to check
    
    ws.Range("L65:L66").FormatConditions.Delete 'clear any flags
    
    L65empty = Len(ws.Range("L65").Value) = 0
    L66empty = Len(ws.Range("L66").Value) = 0
    
    If (Not L65empty) And (Not L66empty) Then Exit Sub 'all ok
    
    'one or both are empty
    If L65empty And L66empty Then
        msg = "Please fill in L65 and L66"
        AddCFFill ws.Range("L65:L66"), vbRed
    ElseIf L66empty Then
        msg = "Please fill in L66"
        AddCFFill ws.Range("L66"), vbRed
    Else
        msg = "Please fill in L65"
        AddCFFill ws.Range("L65"), vbRed
    End If
    
     MsgBox "If any values are entered in L5:L63 then other values must be filled!" & _
            " (see red-filled cells)" & vbLf & vbLf & _
            msg
    Cancel = True 'cancel the close
    
End Sub


I received a compile error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

In Column L of the "Instruction & Data Input" worksheet, I want to see if any cell from L5:L63 has ANY data in it. If they are ALL empty, I want the sub to not run. If ANY cell from L5:L63 has data in it, AND L65 OR L66 OR both L65 AND L66 are empty, then Fire. If ANY cell in that range is not empty AND L65 is empty, then one message box is called. If ANY cell in that range is not empty AND L66 is empty, then another message box is called. If ANY cell in that range is empty AND BOTH L65/L66 are empty a third different message box is called. I appreciate everything you have suggested so far.

So does that also include the logic in the code you posted, of checking columns N and O?   I fixed my posted code - I was testing as a standalone method and had removed Cancel As Boolean from the sub header.

No, N and O don't need to be checked. If any of the cells in L5:L63 contain any data. I want to make sure that the user knows that they owe data in L65 and L66. I don't want them to be able to close the workbook unless they satisfy L65 and L66 or they erase the data in all cells in L5:L63. When any data is input by user in ANY cell in L5:L63, L65 and L66 should highlight until data is input into those cells. I am going to try to configure what you sent to highlight L65 and L66.

The other odd thing is when it highlighted the cells red, I wasn't able to have them revert back to their previous color without deleting the cells entirely. Even if I removed the code from the workbook.

Added an update.  Please don't include code in your question if it's not related to what you want to do, otherwise we're all going to reasonably assume the posted code somehow reflects what you want, in addition to whatever else you describe in the text...

I edited the question but left the original information on there, until the answer is found. On another worksheet I added several formulas that help me check to see if my conditions were met. If they are met, I get a "Don't call the message" returned. If they aren't met, they check to see what condition isn't being met' one, the  other or both, and tells me what message should be called: Call battery terminal connection (-) message, Call battery terminal connection (+) message, or Call both messages. I had to step away and break it down even for my own sake. Let me know what you think.

I think if you're already using VBA to check the sheet then adding formulas into the mix just adds complexity.  Did you try my second example?

Is the VBA supposed to go on the sheet or the workbook? I tried in both and I couldn't get it to work. Each time I tried to update the conditions and it wouldn't do anything. No message boxes, didn't prevent me from closing the workbook. The formulas were for my own sanity.

It should be in the ThisWorkbook code module.  For testing purposes you can move the Cancel As Boolean from the method header into the declarations list, and run it using F5.  I just noticed I forgot to switch back before posting - fixed above.

I received a compile error: "Sub or function not defined". The only highlighted area of the code is the line 19 "AddCFFill". With any variation of combinations (range L5:L63 blank, both L65 and L66 blank, all not blank, etc.) this returns that same error.

Did you include the Sub AddCFFill (in ThisWorkbook or in a regular module)?  You will need that to run the code.  It was already in the first code I posted so I didn't repeat it.

I didn't originally have that in there. Would it sit under the other sub like the original post had it? I tested removing all the conditional formatting, and the message box fired no problem. I then added the Sub AddCFFill at the bottom of in Thisworkbook, and now I get a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error  with line 9 being highlighted.

Line 9 is which line?

ws.Range("L65:L66").FormatConditions.Delete 'clear any flags

Works fine for me.  Is your worksheet protected?  Might be easier to just add a CF to L65:L66 which highlights the cell if L5:L63 has data but the cell is empty.

The worksheet is protected, but all of the cells in range L5:L63 and L65, L66, are not. Almost every worksheet in this workbook has to be protected. I just allowed those cells to be formatted prior to protecting the sheet. and it worked. My only question is how do I get the fill formatting to clear in L65 and L66 if all of the above are empty, filled or partially filled? Now L65 and L66 are permanently filled red. I appreciate everything. You are the best!

Move ws.Range("L65:L66").FormatConditions.Delete above the line If Application.CountA(ws.Range("L5:L63")) = 0 Then Exit Sub
